# Variational Autoencoder task for better feature extraction

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, unsupervised-learning, autoencoders, supervised-learning

I have a CNN with the regression task of a single scalar.
I was wondering if an additional task of reconstructing the image (used for learning visual concepts), seen in a DeepMind [presentation](https://youtu.be/yV698Fi2XzE) with the loss and re-parametrization trick of Variational Autoencoder, might help the principal task of regression.

So you can imagine some convolutions with the role of feature extraction with some output X (let's say a vector of 256 values), that X goes into the VAE which computes Z and then the reconstructed image. And then the original regression task would take either X or Z in order to compute that scalar value.

Has anyone tried such an approach, is it worth the work?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not worked on this but I think I can give you a theoretical perspective of using VAE's. Regression is a Supervised Learning task and is basically a mapping from Input to Output where the Neural Net will approximate the function $f(input) = output$.

VAE's on the other hand are good for finding how a latent variable affects the output. For example, if you have a task of training on a persons facial emotions, and if your latent space contains 2 variables $z_1$ and $z_2$ then you might find varying $z_1$ varies the amount of smile on the face, while varying $z_2$ might give the amount of drooping of eyes. I suggest you check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5WoItGTWV54&t=2945s) from Stanford at ~44:00 to see this actually happens or check this [blog](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/variational-autoencoders/). So VAE's might have been useful if your output contained more features which would vary according to variations in latent variables, but a single scalar output can only tell you about the rate of effect on varying a latent variable.

But if your job is only for better regression, Auto-Encoders are the better alternative, since it has an inherent [de-noising](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-glossary-and-terms/denoising-autoencoder) ability and sufficient training might help in de-noising the input, and thus provide better results if classified on the basis of latent variables.

An approach, which I think is kind of similar (to your thinking) has been proposed by Kingma, et al. for Semi Supervised learning in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5298.pdf). The paper has very poor description of the method so I would suggest you check out this [blog](http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/semi-supervised-learning-with-variational-autoencoders/). They have used an additional classifier for reconstruction of the original input and trained the classifier when labels are present.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your references. I will definitely read them. Actually my neural network has multiple outputs, but I just presented the problem in a simpler manner. By doing this, you really made a good point with "a single scalar output can only tell you about the rate of effect on varying a latent variable".